# DCOM automation batch file

Tags: batch, batch-file, automation, dcom

I wrote a batch file that changes settings in Component Services on the my computer properties. (I also just realized I need to make this for individual operating systems which is OK but time consuming.)
In Component Services there are DCOM settings. If you look at the properties of one of the services in there they have multiple tabs. The two tabs I need help with automating are the *Security* tab and the *Identity* tab.

The Security tab has three sections. *Launch and activation permissions*, *Access permissions* and *Configuration permissions*. Launch and activation permissions and access permissions look to flow down from my computer properties.

I need to have a batch file that sets Start → Administrative Tools  → Component Services → Computers → My Computer → DCOM Config → when you right-click on one and go to Properties there is a tab called *Identity* with different options to choose. I need the batch file to make it select "The launching User".

I also need to have a batch file that sets Component Services → Computers → My Computer → DCOM Config → when you right-click on one and go to Properties there's a *Security* tab with different options to choose. I  need the batch file to add "Everyone", "Anonymous Logon", "Administrators" and "Authenticated Users" into the Configuration Permissions section.

[DCOM Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFDOn.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your post and remove the unrelated info. A good stack exchange question is, “How do I do....x...y....z?” If your question is how to modify some setting from a batch file then ask that, and be specific about which setting(s) you want to change, possibly showing a screenshot of the setting. I don’t see how most of the stuff you included in this post clarifies the question - if there even is one?

Comment: Can we take this off of hold? I need help with this.

Comment: Your question boils down to "how do I change the identity and security settings for a service in DCOM config from the command prompt?" It's fine to include enough detail to make sure everyone understands, but too much information just gets in the way. Further, you can include some pictures and others can edit your post to include them.

Comment: Still need this off of hold. This forum is just getting my time wasted right now.

Comment: Your question will be removed from hold AFTER you complete the edits to make it sufficiently clear that community members judge it OK to open. The Hold process is there to give you time to improve the question. Asking for it to be reopened is counter productive: improving the question is the only and best way to get it opened.

Comment: It is clear what i need. Maybe it is above what you understand, it tells you exactly .